# Different runtime behavior for non-generic typing

Tags: python, python-3.8

Consider these two scenarios:

```
from queue import Queue
my_q: Queue[int] = Queue()
print(f"queue={my_q}")
```

and

```
from queue import Queue

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_q: Queue[int] = Queue()

my_class = MyClass()
print(f"queue={my_class.my_q}")
```

Running the former (expectedly) throws a `TypeError`:

```
$ python3 run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    my_q: Queue[int] = Queue()
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

However the latter doesn't, and proceeds to the print statement without issue:

```
$ python3 run.py
queue=<queue.Queue object at 0x7fb40265f730>
```

I would expect a `TypeError` in both cases. Why is there no `TypeError` when the `Queue[int]` type is inside of a class's `__init__` method?

Comment: I somehow never noticed this before, but you can actually put garbage in the attribute annotation and it still runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both module and class annotations are accessible at runtime, and thus evaluated:

```py
# example.py
a: int = 4
print(__annotations__)  # {'a': <class 'int'>}
```

In contrast, the annotations local to a function are not accessible and thus never evaluated.

---

As per [PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/), function *parameter* annotations are evaluated  and available at runtime:

> Once compiled, a function's annotations are available via the function's `__annotations__` attribute.

As per [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/), module and class level annotations *of simple names* are evaluated and available at runtime. Annotations inside functions are explicitly not evaluated or stored for efficiency:

> In addition, at the module or class level, if the item being annotated is a simple name, then it and the annotation will be stored in the `__annotations__` attribute of that module or class (mangled if private) as an ordered mapping from names to evaluated annotations.
> [...]
> Also the value of having annotations available locally does not offset the cost of having to create and populate the annotations dictionary on every function call. Therefore, annotations at function level are not evaluated and not stored.

With [PEP 563 / Python 3.10](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/), no annotations are evaluated immediately anymore. However, annotations of module, class, and function-parameter names may still be evaluated lazily and should thus be valid expressions. Annotations local to functions remain inaccessible and thus unevaluated.

> Note that as per PEP 526, local variable annotations are not evaluated at all since they are not accessible outside of the function's closure.

Comment: This sounds like it is the correct answer; is there a docs link which says this is the expected behaviour?

Comment: @kaya3 Good point. I've added relevant sections from appropriate PEPs.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to how python evaluates type hints, and how this differs depending on whether the statement is inside a function or not. The type hint as stated is invalid in python 3.8 (though not in 3.9) and is probably not evaluated at all in the **init** method.